# What is the meaning what's the meaning of "I'll get it " in this passage?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of,  I'll get it ,  in below passage : 
Penny was picking up a pile of wood , doing jody's work. Jody ran to him .
"I'll get it , Pa! " . Jody said .
I think that " I'll get it "or "I get it " means here " I do it " , is it correct? Or if I would say " I've got it " , it could be mean " I've done it " , correct?

Comment: Is Jody's father's name *Penny*?

Comment: Yes! Penny is Jody's father.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that Jody's father's name is *Penny* *I'll* get it means I will take the wood that you are carrying.

A simpler way to say it would be:

> Penny was picking up a pile of wood, doing jody's work. Jody ran to him. 
>   "I will take it, pa!" Jody said.

Comment: Thank you ! I think I understand it now! Get means here take sth or carry sth from one place to another place.  You know what ? Before I thought it means I'll do it , for example if your mother said you " Do your homework " or " clean your room " you could say "  I'll get it " instead of " I'll do it " . But now I think I was completely wrong.  It just means "take " here. For example you can say " I'll get an umbrella, it's raining " instead of " I'll take an umbrella " or " I'll get her some woods " instead of " I'll take her some woods " I mean get and take are synonymous where you carry sth